# A different upper bound for the binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, induction, binomial-coefficients, upper-lower-bounds

I need to prove the following statement:

If $3\leq k <  t$ then
\begin{equation*}
    \binom{t}{k} < 2^{t-1}-k+1.
\end{equation*}

I was given the hint to prove it by induction over $t$ with $k$ fixed, which seems very reasonable.

The base case is rather easy to see:
\begin{equation*}
    \binom{k+1}{k} = k+1 < 2^k-k+1 \Leftrightarrow 2k < 2^k
\end{equation*}

However I am struggling hard with the inductive step. My approach for now is using Pascal's identity to obtain
\begin{equation}
    \binom{t+1}{k} = \binom{t}{k}+\binom{t}{k-1}
\end{equation}
At this point, I would like to apply induction to both terms, but my induction is over $t$ so I am not allowed to do that. (I tried to do double induction, but the induction over $k$ seems even harder).

In the case that $k\geq \frac{t+1}{2}$ the second term is smaller or equal than the first one, so I apply induction hypothesis
\begin{equation*}
    \binom{t+1}{k} < 2\left(2^{t-1}-k+2\right)=2^t-2k+2 < 2^t-k+1
\end{equation*}

However, I am very confused for what to do in the remaining case $k>\frac{t+1}{2}$.

Any help or hint will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deal with the formula
\begin{equation}
    \binom{t+1}{k} = \binom{t}{k}+\binom{t}{k-1},
\end{equation}
you can deal with the following statement by induction on $t$ :
for all $t\geq 4$, for all $k$ such that $3\leq k<t$,
$$\binom{t}{k}\leq 2^{t-1}-k+1.$$

- Base case : $t=4,t=5$ (easy to show).
- Induction : if $4\leq k \leq t-1$
  \begin{align*}\binom{t+1}{k} = \binom{t}{k}+\binom{t}{k-1}&\leq 2^{t-1}-k+1+2^{t-1}-(k-1)+1\\
  &\leq 2^t-k+1,
  \end{align*}
  and if $k=3$ or $k=t$ it's trivial.

Comment: But then, shouldn't you prove the inductive step for $k$? namely $\binom{t}{k+1} < 2^{t-1}-(k+1)-1$

Comment: When I make the induction, I need to show the formula with $t+1$ and $k$ for all $k$ such that $3\leq k<t+1$. I fix one $k$ and I use the induction from $t$ which is valid for all $k$ such that $3\leq k <t $ (hence the separation of cases in the induction)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Notice that $$\binom{t+1}{k} = \frac{(t+1)!}{(t+1-k)!k!} = \frac{t+1}{t+1-k}\cdot \frac{t!}{(t-k)!k!} =\frac{t+1}{t+1-k}\cdot\binom{t}{k}.$$